# Extract the Name and Span of Regex Matched Groups

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex that looks like:

```
rgx = '(?P<foo>ABC)(?P<bar>DEF)?(?P<norf>HIJK)'
```

Getting the matched string is no problem `m.group(name)`.  However, I need to extract the **name** and **span** of the matched groups (or even just the span by name) and haven't found a way to do this.  I would like to do something like:

```
p = re.compile(p, re.IGNORECASE)
m = p.match(targetstring)
#then do something to set 'all' to the list of match objects
for mo in all
   print mo.name() + '->' + mo.span()
```

So for example the input string 'ABCDEFHIJK' should generate the output:

```
'foo'  -> (0, 3)
'bar'  -> (3, 6)
'norf' -> (6, 10)
```

Thanks!

Comment: post an example along with the expected output.

Comment: @laike9m span is a method belonging to the regex MatchObject. It tell which portion of the string was matched.

Comment: @AvinashRaj aok, i posted an example.

Comment: Then just use the `matchObj.span([group])`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You iterate over the names of the matched groups (the keys of `groupdict`) and print the corresponding `span` attribute:

```
rgx = '(?P<foo>ABC)(?P<bar>DEF)?(?P<norf>HIJK)'
p = re.compile(rgx, re.IGNORECASE)
m = re.match(p, 'ABCDEFHIJKLM')

for key in m.groupdict():
    print key, m.span(key)
```

This prints:

```
foo (0, 3)
bar (3, 6)
norf (6, 10)
```

**Edit**: Since the keys of a dictionary are unordered, you may wish to explicitly choose the order in which the keys are iterated over. In the example below, `sorted(...)` is a list of the group names sorted by the corresponding dictionary value (the `span` tuple):

```
for key in sorted(m.groupdict().keys(), key=m.groupdict().get):
    print key, m.span(key)
```

Comment: @georg Oops. Fixed the typo. Thanks!

Comment: That's better, but still no cigar. `groupdict` is a dictionary, so the order of results is not guaranteed.

Comment: @georg True, but OP didn't specify that any order was necessary. If it is, it's straightforward to choose the order that the keys are chosen from the `dict`.

Comment: @ajcr: comments are intended to help askers, answerers and future readers, not to attack anyone. Instead of defending yourself, please improve your post by pointing out that the results are in the random order and suggest a workaround for those who needs them sorted.

Comment: @georg Apologies if the tone of my previous comment was defensive; that wasn't intended at all. I will add the note about order to my answer.

Comment: @ajcr: now it's perfect. Have a +1 ))

Comment: @georg thank you for your corrections and suggestions, they're appreciated. (And +1 for your answer which I've just read and learned about `groupindex` from!)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`RegexObject.groupindex`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.groupindex):

```
p = re.compile(rgx, re.IGNORECASE)
m = p.match('ABCDEFHIJK')

for name, n in sorted(m.re.groupindex.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]):
    print name, m.group(n), m.span(n)
```