# Get the spans of named groups in order in one line

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex like this `r'(?P<mark1>)|\s+(?P<mark2>)|(?P<mark3>)\s+'` (sample regex not the actual one) and I want to get the spans of the captured groups in matches in order.

For example:
1. `[match.span() for match in re.finditer(regex, string)]` returns the spans in order but gives the span of whole match not just the captured group.
2. `[match.span('mark1') for match in re.finditer(regex, string)]` returns the spans in order of captured groups but puts `(-1, -1)` for other named groups.

So, can I get the spans of the named groups in order of the matches in one line, as simple as the above queries?

I found the following way:
`[match.span(name) for match in re.finditer(regex, string) for name, value in match.groupdict().items() if value is not None]`

Is there a simple one?

An example to present my scenario:

```
import re
s = "asfasdf      32392  ..///?%        aslf    /././/               342"
reg = r'(?P<mark1>[a-z]+)|\s+(?P<mark2>[0-9]+)|(?P<mark3>[./?%]+)\s+'
print([match.span(name) for match in re.finditer(reg, s) for name, value in match.groupdict().items() if value is not None])
print([match.span() for match in re.finditer(reg, s)])
print
print([match.span('mark1') for match in re.finditer(reg, s)])
print([match.span('mark2') for match in re.finditer(reg, s)])
print([match.span('mark3') for match in re.finditer(reg, s)])
```

Output:

```
[(0, 7), (13, 18), (20, 27), (35, 39), (43, 49)]
[(0, 7), (7, 18), (20, 35), (35, 39), (43, 64)]

[(0, 7), (-1, -1), (-1, -1), (35, 39), (-1, -1)]
[(-1, -1), (13, 18), (-1, -1), (-1, -1), (-1, -1)]
[(-1, -1), (-1, -1), (20, 27), (-1, -1), (43, 49)]
```

Comment: Should see the target string. It's confusing without it

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your pattern. All the capturing groups are zero-length, so the first one will always match.

Comment: @Aminah Nuraini There are three regex parsers here separated by `|`, the target string contains characters that will be matched by at least one of the regex parsers. Say, one regex parser matches lowercase alphabet, the other numbers and the other special characters...the target string is `"asfasdf 32392 ..///?% aslf /./.// 342"`

Comment: @Blckknght I didn't write the actual regex. Here is a sample one `r'(?P<mark1>[a-z]+)|\s+(?P<mark2>[0-9]+)|(?P<mark3>[./?%]+)\s+'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, the second tuple and last tuple are different. If I increase spaces, it might be more visible.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and include the input and code you use? A link to an external site like ideone is not stable.

Comment: @DisplayName Thanks! Done.

Comment: It is impossible to use a simpler correct way. The point is that `re.finditer` always returns all matches starting with the whole match (and then capture groups). I have not heard of any override versions of finditer. `re.findall` does not return match objects :(

Comment: Oh :( If `span` could be changed to accept list of named-group's names it would have been perfect! @WiktorStribiżew
Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Luckily, [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465299/extract-the-name-and-span-of-regex-matched-groups) has a solution where you don't have to run **finditer** multiple times. For the current question, the code is:

```
s = "asfasdf      32392  ..///?%        aslf    /././/               342"
reg = r'(?P<mark1>[a-z]+)|\s+(?P<mark2>[0-9]+)|(?P<mark3>[./?%]+)\s+'
p = re.compile(reg, re.IGNORECASE)
for m in re.finditer(p,s):
    for key,value in m.groupdict().items():
        if value is not None:
            print(key, m.span(key))
```

and dict ordering is no longer an issue since Python 3.6

Comment: I tried your code with the example I gave above, the match object "m" only matched this: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='asfasdf'>

Comment: and so it gave wrong output:
mark2 (-1, -1)
mark1 (0, 7)
mark3 (-1, -1)

Comment: Thanks for the remark, and you're right. I've updated the code use *re.finditer* (once) instead of .*re.match* Not as straight-forward as it was, but still workable. Hope you agree!

Comment: Hi, I am sorry, if you see my question I already mentioned this solution actually, though it's in the form of list comprehension. Thank you for your time !